# Ubuntu freeze after upgrade installation interrupt

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I was upgrading my Ubuntu distro and shut down the laptop in the middle of the installation process. Upon restart, I only get a black screen with these messages:

```
Starting Hardware RNG entropy gatherer daemon: (Hardware RNG device inode not found)
/etc/rc2.d/S21rng-tools: Cannot find a hardware RNG device to use.
saned disabled: edit /etc/default/saned
* Restoring resolver state... [OK]
```

And then it waits there forever.

Is there any way to restore Ubuntu or does it need a fresh install?

I would hate to have to reinstall and reconfigure my development environments all over again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have hosed the installation and you need to do a fresh OS install.

If you've been doing proper backups **of your whole system**, restore from your latest backup and then redo the upgrade. You should do such a backup before any OS update.

If you don't have such a backup, then wipe the system and do a full OS reinstall.  Even if you can kludge the system into running again, there are too many ways the system could be broken to trust it further.

There are no circumstances under which I would do anything with such a system other than restore from backups and upgrade, or wipe and reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. My Ubuntu VM would start up but not get to the login prompt. When I booted with verbose on, that "Restoring resolver state" was the last line on my console.

This is how I fixed it:

1. Boot into the Ubuntu live CD (change the screen resolution if you have to using the `displays` program).
2. Open a terminal. Determine which disk you are using as your "boot" disk:

   ```
   $ sudo fdisk -l
   ```

   Mine was `/dev/sda1`.
3. In the same terminal, create a folder in the `tmp` directory:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p /tmp/sda1
   ```

   Mount the boot disk to that folder:

   ```
   $ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/sda1
   ```
4. Mount some of your livecd directories so we can successfully run all our commands:

   ```
   for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /tmp/sda1$i; done
   ```
5. Chroot into `/tmp/sda1`:

   ```
   $ sudo chroot /tmp/sda1 /bin/bash
   ```

   It's basically as if you booted and logged into your computer. You can now do `grub-install` to fix the boot issue within that shell:

   ```
   $ sudo grub-install /dev/sda
   ```
6. For good measure, also do the following before exiting:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install -f
   ```
7. Unmount and exit the chroot:

   ```
   $ sudo umount -a
   $ exit
   ```

If that doesn't work, try changing your Linux kernel on bootup to a previous one. You can do this with the chroot method too.